# Chart.Js - Display only specific (fixed) X axis labels

Tags: chart.js

I need to create a Chart.js that displays, by default, only the labels 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 and 0.5 in X axis. In case the value 0.013 needs to be plotted, it should be between 0 and 0.1, but without displaying its specific label. The same for value 0.389, where it needs to be displayed between 0.3 and 0.4, with same behavior.
Currently my graph is displayed like this:
[image]

The desired is something like this:
[image]

Note: even there are no values for some "regions", the labels 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 and 0.5 should be displayed.
I tried my different options, and the "best" that I found was to control the number of labels to be displayed, but it is not what I am looking for:

```
config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                data: [],
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor:'#E16972',
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                display: false
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            elements: {
                point:{
                    radius: 0
                }
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'psd'
                    },
                    /*ticks: {
                         max: 2,
                         min: 0,
                        stepSize: 0.2
                    },*/
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false,
                        labelString: 'frequency'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function(dataLabel, index) {
                            // Hide the label of every 2nd dataset. return null to hide the grid line too
                            return index % 2 === 0 ? dataLabel : '';
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your sample code does not show any data, so I had to make an assumption on how it might look like.

Within a vertical bar chart, individual bars get evenly spread among the available space on the x-axis. Therefore, the values for the x-axis (the labels) don't matter in your case, their number only has to match the number of data values.

The number of data values however matters and it has to fit the linear scale. Therefore, in the runnable code snippet below, I provide 15 values (some of them are zero) and end up having 3 values for each section of 0.1 width.

```js
const data = [0, 0.0003, 0.0008, 0.00025, 0.0012, 0.0018, 0, 0.00078, 0.00034, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: data.map(v => 'x'),
        datasets: [{
            data: data,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: '#E16972',
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            display: false
        },
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'psd'
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    stepSize: 0.001
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                    display: false
                },
                {
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'frequency'
                    },
                    type: 'linear',
                    ticks: {
                        max: 0.5,
                        stepSize: 0.1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: is there a way to display only the X values 0, 0.1, 0.3 and 0.5 ?

Comment: @Alan Gularte: Please post a new question for this new issue